# Cover Java Functional Interface in JUnit

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'm writing unit test using JUnit and Mockito. I'm trying to test the logic inside a runnable block. Using argument captor works fine when the captured argument wasn't a stream, but when the argument is a stream, error of `java.lang.IllegalStateException: source already consumed or closed`. I understand that once the `try-catch` block completed the stream will be closed, but then how can we test the logic inside the runnable block?

Here's the bean's logic to be tested,

```
...

@Transactional
public void execute() {
   try (Stream<Object> data = jpaRepository.fetchStream()) {
      Stream<Runnable> tasks = data.map(t -> () -> {
         // logic to be tested goes here
      });
      
      someBean.method(tasks);
   }
}
```

Here's the unit test

```
...

@InjectMocks
private App app;

@Mock
private SomeBean someBean;

@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<Stream<Runable>> argumentCaptor;

@Test
void test() {
   app.execute();

   verify(someBean).method(argumentCaptor.capture());

   argumentCaptor.getValue().findFirst().get().run(); // Here the error thrown: java.lang.IllegalStateException: source already consumed or closed
}
```

Comment: can you share more abuout what is happening after this `data.map(...)` ? do you have any terminal operations such as `forEach` or `collect` ?

Comment: @EmanuelTrandafir the purpose of the `data.map(...)` was to produce a `stream` of `runnable` so the `tasks` variable can be passed to `someBean.method(tasks)`  to be executed by the `someBean` bean. I've updated the code sample to fix some typos

Answer (score 0):

The generated `Stream` is lazy, so you have to make sure it's consumed before `someBean.method()` returns. The solution varies depending on your need:

The simplest solution would be to pass something that's not lazy to the bean, such as a list. Just collect your stream before passing it and you'll be fine.

If that's not an option, you'll have to make sure the test bean does the collection as soon as the method is called. That should be doable with a subclass, or a custom mocked implementation.

Comment: can you help to show a simplified example of subclass or custom mocked implementation solutions?

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the question, look at this example. We map the stream to a stream and then we store it inside an object. (here it's the case of `StreamHolder`, in your case it's the `ArgumentCaptor`).

As you can see, the stream is stored there and then closed (when the try with resources closes). After that point, if we try to access the elements of the stream, we'll get the `IllegalStateException` you mentioned:

```
@Test
void test() {
    StreamHolder holder = new StreamHolder();

    try(Stream<Integer> ids = Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)) {
        Stream<Runnable> tasks = ids
                .map(id -> () -> System.out.println("processing id "+ id));
        holder.setStream(tasks);
    }

    holder.getStream().findFirst();
    // java.lang.IllegalStateException: source already consumed or closed
}

@Data
class StreamHolder {
    Stream<Runnable> stream;
}
```

---

One solution would be not to use streams to pass/store data. Streams are primarily made for processing their elements.

Therefore, collecting them first and passing a Collection this `method` will be safer and it will fix the test as well.

```
List<Runnable> tasks = data.map(t -> () -> {
      // logic to be tested goes here
   })
   .toList();

someBean.method(tasks);
```

---

Other options (without collecting the data) would be:

1. Process the data inside the try-with-resources, you can try with `paralleStream` (and a dedicated thread pool) or with completable futures and join everything before the end of the try-catch.
2. You can try doing paginated queries instead of streaming from the database to avoid this scenario and process smaller batches asynchronously/in parallel
3. If you are using `mongo`, there are some `reactive repositories` - unfortunately with `jdbc` this is not possible and you might need to look into `rjdbc` if you consider this reactive path

Comment: To give some context, the method in the `someBean` bean will process the runnable in threads. later there will be a process in the method like `tasks.map(task -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(task, Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nthreads))).toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);`. In this case I wan't to avoid to collect all the data because I don't want to load the whole data into the memory. Does that make sense? Or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: i see - still, passing the stream seems a little risky. I have updated my answer with a few other alternatives. I hope it helps - if it does, I would appreciate an upvote:)